# fullcalendar resourceDay view not open when resources and event json file are empty

Tags: jquery, css, json, twitter-bootstrap, yii

i creating agenda page for event, i used bootstrap modal to display the calendar if the resources and event  json file are empty ,fullcalendar not showing the modal
my full calendar resourceDay view code

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
      },


      defaultView: 'resourceDay',
      slotMinutes: 10,
      selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
                    editable: true,
                    contentHeight: 480,
                     titleFormat: {

         day: 'dddd MMM d, yyyy'   //whatever date format you want here
      },
       resources: <?php echo json_encode($return_resource); ?>,              
      events:<?php echo json_encode($return_arr); ?>,
```

}

modal page i used to display the calendar and one popover
 
    
      
        
          ×
          Modal title

```
        <div id="calendar" class="calendersize">       
        </div>
      <div class="popover fade bottom in facebox_align_city margin69" id="newSession" >
<!--<div class="arrow"></div>-->
<h3 class="popover-title">New session – Session editor</h3>
<div class="popover-content" >
    <form id="sessionForm" accept-charset="utf-8" >
        <div class="form-group">               
            <div class="required">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div style="background:lightslategray;color:white;">
                                     <span id="agendaDate" style="padding-left: 50px;font-weight: bold;"></span>
                                </div>

                                                                   <!--<input type="text" id="" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: black;color:white;" >--> 
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row customized_input1">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div id="ddd"></div>
                                    <p>Start Time</p>
                                     <select id="startTime"  class="form-control" > </select>

                                </div>
                             <div class="col-lg-6">
                                 <p>End Time</p>
                                   <select id="endTime"  class="form-control" > </select>

                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row customized_input1">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <p> Details</p>
                                <input type='text' id="sessionTitle" placeholder='Session Title' class="form-control" />
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row customized_input1">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">                       
                                <textarea id="sessionDescription"cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Session Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>


                        <div class="row customized_input1">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">         
                                <div id="addnewhall">
                                    <input type="text" id="selectedHall" class="form-control" name="venueSel" readonly="readonly" watermark="Enter hall" placeholder="Enter hall" >
                                    <input type="hidden" id="resourceId" class="form-control" />
                                </div>

                            <div class="hall_list" style="position:relative;margin-top: 10px;">
                                <ul id="hallList">
                                     <?php 
                                             $query1=AgendaResource::model()->findAll("eventId = '$eventId'");
                                             $count=0;
                                                    foreach($query1 as $row1)
                                                   {
                                                        $count=$count+1;

                                                      $resourceId = $row1['resourceId'];
                                                       $resourceName = $row1['resourceName'];

                                                   ?> 


                                            <li id="hallListItem" value="<?php echo $resourceId; ?>"><?php echo $resourceName; ?><span id="removelist">X</span></li>
                                                   <?php }  ?>

                                </ul>
                               <div style="float:left;"><input id="newhall" type="text"  watermark="Create new hall" maxlength="28" class="form-control" style="border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px;"></div>
                               <div style="float:left;"><input type="button" id="addList" value="Add" class="form-control" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 0px;"></div>   
                            </div>


                            </div>                        
                        </div>


                    <div class="waittoaddhall">
                        <div class="row customized_input1">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <input type='text' id="location" placeholder='location' class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                 <p>Session Speaker</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-8">                               
                                <form  role="search">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                <div class="btn btn-default form-control" id="speakerSearch"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                               <div id="addSpeaker" class="btn btn-small btn-default" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> New</div>                           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-lg-8"> 
                                   <input type='hidden' id="speakerId"  class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="row customized_input1">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                                    <div class="ss_list speakers">
                                        <ul id="speakersList">


                                           <?php $query=SpeakersList::model()->findAll("eventId = '$eventId'");

                                                    foreach($query as $row)
                                                   {
                                                      $speakerId = $row['speakerId'];
                                                       $name = $row['name'];

                                                   ?> 
                                              <li> 
                                               <div class='chkDiv'>
                                                   <input type='checkbox' class='chkSpeaker' value='<?php echo $speakerId ?>'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id='editSpeaker'><?php echo $name; ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='delDiv'> X </span>
                                               </div>
                                               </li>
                                             <?php  } ?>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                      </div>    


        <div class="popover_buttons">
            <input type='button' class="btn btn-small btn-success" value='Save' id="submit" />
            <input type='button' class="btn btn-small btn-warning" value='Cancel' id="popovercancel"/>
        </div>
     </div><!-- end of the col-12-lg -->

           </div>   
        </div> <!-- end fo form-group -->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

please help me how solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public function getJsonStaff() {
>     $staff = array();
>     if (count($this->staff) > 0) {
>         foreach ($this->staff as $s) {
>             $user = array();
>             $user['id'] = (int) $s->id; //id needs to an integer
>             $user['name'] = $s->first_name . ' ' . $s->last_name;
>             array_push($staff, $user);
>         }
>     } else {
>         $user['id'] = 1; //id needs to an integer
>         $user['name'] = 'This branch has no staff';
>         array_push($staff, $user);
>     }
>     return Response::json($staff);
> }
> ```